# How can electrons manage to be at the same distance from the nucleus at all positions in p, d and f orbitals?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

[image: example]In quantum mechanics electrons are arranged in certain orbitals namely s, p, d and f orbitals.The position of the electrons are determined by 4 sets of quantum numbers n, l, m and s. Electrons can only be at a fixed distance from a nucleus which is determined by the quantum number n, but in p, d and f orbitals how  does it manage to be at a fixed distance at every point in the region of these orbitals?(here is an example of p orbital in image)

Comment: There is no fixed distance.

Comment: Hm, it's not very hard to guess what the OP's misunderstanding is: The *average* distance only depends on n in hydrogen-like atom, as the energy levels of all l,m,s quantum states are *degenerate*.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're confusing what the orbital shapes represent. The shapes are probability distributions-which means that you're most likely to find the electron somewhere within the shape.

> Electrons can only be at a fixed distance from a nucleus

This is false

> which is determined by n quantum number

The `n` quantum number tells you how *big* the orbital is-not precisely how far away the electron is.

In reality, the electron is moving around the atom, and is *probably* somewhere within the orbital shape.